# Why won't my video background be responsive along with my login box?

Tags: html, css, laravel, debugging, laravel-blade

I'm facing this issue where after successfully making my login box appear on top of the video background, the background itself isn't responsive because there exists a horizontal scroll when making my screen smaller (dragging view left and right when dev tools is open) as well as the login box appearing minuscule on top of the background on mobile view.  Screenshot attached for reference

[mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqe2c.png)

I've literally tried almost everything CSS-wise and feel like I'm running out of options.  What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Here's my blade file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

<video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
    <source src="https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/mp4/Mt_Baker.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Login') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                        {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Login') }}
                                </button>

                                @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                        {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                                    </a>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Here's my CSS for the video:

```
video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 0;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do add the object-fit: cover; and change width and height to 100% to the video element

```
video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: Can you set the width and height to 100%?

width: 100%;
height: 100%;

Just tried it here: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/n3c7qsro/)